# Adding business days in a DAX time intelligence measure

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I am writing a custom time intelligence measure in DAX to calculate a disbursement period which is 30 days + the following Friday from a payment. The solution below appears to work. However, I need to only include business/working days which prevents me from using the `DATEADD()` function.

How could I go about skipping the weekend days in the count of 30?

```
Expected Amount Disbursed = 
CALCULATE([Total Agency Component Paid], 
    FILTER(ALL('Calendar'),
        DATEADD('Calendar'[Date], 30,DAY) - MOD(DATEADD('Calendar'[Date], 30,DAY), 7) + 6 > MIN('Calendar'[Date]) &&
        DATEADD('Calendar'[Date], 30,DAY) - MOD(DATEADD('Calendar'[Date], 30,DAY), 7) + 6 < MAX('Calendar'[Date])
)
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to compute dates considering working days is to add a column to the Calendar table with the progressive number of working days. Assuming we have the column IsWorkingDay in our Calendar table this new calculated column can be defined as

```
WorkingDayNumber = 
VAR CurrentDate = 'Calendar'[Date]
RETURN 
SUMX(
    FILTER(
        'Calendar',
        'Calendar'[Date] <= CurrentDate
    ),
    'Calendar'[IsWorkingDay]
)
```

where IsWorkingDay contains 1 for working days or 0 for non working days.

Then to compute the date after 30 working days since the date in the current row context

```
VAR WorkingDayNumber = 'Calendar'[WorkingDayNumber]
VAR DatePlus30WorkingDays =
     CALCULATE(
          MIN( 'Calendar'[Date] ),
          'Calendar'[IsWorkingDay] = 1,
          'Calendar'[WorkingDayNumber] = WorkingDayNumber + 30,
          REMOVEFILTERS( 'Calendar' )
     )
```